# Alternate Equation of a Line in Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be distinct complex numbers. Show that the locus of points $tz_1+(1-t)z_2$, $-\infty<t<\infty$, describes the line through $z_1$ and $z_2$.

I am having trouble on how to proceed with this problem. In my opinion, the given expression would constitute a parametrization of the line through $z_1$ and $z_2$. Please advice me on how to proceed in showing that the given expression really is the line through the two distinct complex numbers.

Comment: Differentiate with respect to t?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equation of a line on a complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188403/equation-of-a-line-on-a-complex-plane)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert to familiar real Cartesian coordinates.

Letting $z_k = x_k + y_ki$, you can express the equation as $(x_1t + x_2(1-t) + i((y_1 - y_2)t + y_2)$

If you treat that as a generalised point on an Argand diagram, its coordinates are:$((x_1t + x_2(1-t), ((y_1 - y_2)t + y_2))$

To find the slope of the line joining two points, consider different $t$ values, $t_1, t_2$.

The slope of the line joining those simplifies (after some simple algebra) to $\displaystyle \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$, which is a constant independent of the $t$ values you choose, meaning that the equation describes a straight line.

Finally, set $t=1$ and then $t=0$ to verify that the line passes through $(x_1, y_1) $ and $(x_2, y_2)$ respectively.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your good clear explanation. Actually, I worked it out after your analysis and I believe in your second line you should have $x_{1}t$ instead of $x_2$.

Comment: @Analysis15 Good catch! Sorry I typo-ed when transcribing from my scribble. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as $t(z_1 - z_2) + z_2$.  At $t=0$ it goes through $z_2$ and at $t=1$ it passes through $z_1$. As $t\rightarrow \pm \infty $ the line extends in opposite directions to $|\infty$|.

**Edit:** Note that it is a line because $(z_1 - z_2)$ is a vector.  All variation comes from $t$ which has the effect of stretching the vector.

Comment: But have you shown this is actually a line, i.e. having a constant slope?

Comment: So does $t^n(z_1-z_2)+ z_2$ for all odd positive integers $n$.

Comment: @Deepak, good point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $w=z_1-z_2$, so then you have $f(t)=wt+z_2$.  The dot product between $w$ and $iw$ is zero since they are orthogonal vectors, so the dot product between $f$ and $iw$ is just a real constant $z_2\cdot iw$.  This means every value $f(t)$ satisfies $ax+by=z_2\cdot iw$, where $iw=a+bi$ and $x+iy=f(t)$.