# Geometry with Complex Number

Tags: geometry

My book says Equation of a line perpendicular to the line $z\bar{a}+\bar{z}a+b=0$ is $z\bar{a}+\bar{z}a+ci=0$, (where $c$ is a real number).

Can anyone explain why just multiplying $c$ by $i$ we can get line perpendicular to given line.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: multiplication by $i$ rotate point $\frac{\pi}{2}$ counterclockwise in complex plane

Comment: [The same exact question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188403/equation-of-a-line-on-a-complex-plane/3189297), see if this helps

Comment: Also for the perpendicular line, it should be $z\bar{a}-\bar{z}a+ci=0$, can you please verify once?